# ¿Se puede descargar una base de datos de phpmyadmin desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy pensando en habilitar un boton o un enlace para descargar el archivo .SQL que genera phpmyadmin de la base de datos que se esta usando. Pero de verdad no tengo idea de si esto se puede hacer. Si alguien sabe como se puede realizar y me puede ayudar, agradecido, si esto no se puede hacer haganmelo saber para sacarme esa idea. Gracias!

Comment: Podrías empezar investigando sobre el comando [`mysqldump`](http://librosweb.es/tutorial/como-hacer-copias-de-seguridad-de-una-base-de-datos-mysql/) que permite crear y restaurar copias de seguridad de una base de datos.

Comment: Hola Luis, realiza el [tour] para saber como funcionamos. Te recomiendo [ask].